# How do I save information in a UILabel when switching between viewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have several UILabels that have certain values within them. When I switch to a different viewController and comeback to original view I lose my UILabel's values. How do I retain information while switching through two viewControllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I can give with the information you provided is to use `viewWillDisappear` to save the values of the labels to properties on your viewController.  However, how did the information get into the labels?  The best thing to do, would be to save the values to the properties on your viewController when the information is somehow set on the labels.  Then, you should have some code that populates your labels from your backing properties in `viewWillAppear`.  That way, you're not storing any state in your UI (which is bad) and you have a single direction of flow of the information/state in your viewController (i.e. you're not entering information into a label and also pulling information out).

Comment: Information is entered by keybaord entries and/or button press.

Comment: So you have a UITextField that you receive keyboard input from and then set it as the text property of a UILabel?  If that's the case, then simply also store the keyboard input to a property on your viewController when you set the label's text property.

Comment: Would I put anything within the UILabel(IBAction) code? My 2 UILabels are next and back. There both IBAction buttons.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your last comment.  Do you have information in actual UILabels?  Or did you type UILabel and meant UIButton? I'm confused.

Comment: I have a number value typed within the UITextField. I use a UILabel like a button that does the action.

Comment: You're going to have to be more clear and a little more specific.  Perhaps showing more code would help?  I still don't understand.  If you're using UILabels like UIButtons, why wouldn't you just use a UIButton?

Comment: I have several UITextFields that have information within them( 1,2,3,4). I'm using an UILabel with an IBAction to switch to another view. My problem is that I lose my current information in the UITextFields when I switch. What's the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: From what I can tell, you're not using UILabels at all, but in fact UIButtons.  That's not really important for this topic though. My answer (and other answers on this question) have tried to tell you that you need to store your state in some place it's not going to be unloaded with the view (that's why your text fields are going blank). Placing the information entered in the fields in ivars or properties on your view controller is basically what you need to do.  what part about that is confusing you?

Comment: here is the code I'm using to switch to a different view.  KeyViewController *second = [[KeyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; // View transition
 [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

The labels might be released possibly because of low memory warning. So again, when the labels are loaded, u have to set the value to the labels ., set the values to the labels in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Example of setting "set the value to the labels" in viewDidLoad

Answer (score -2):

The simple way to solve your problem is, save the information in the `NSUserDefault` and in labels as well. When switching again to your view controller, get the values to the labels from `NSUserDefault` in `viewWillAppear`. Hope it will work.

Comment: Could you give an code example of using the NSUserDefault with labels?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is intended to store settings, preferences, and other information for an app.  It is NOT intended to be a datastore.  That sounds like a terrible suggestion and I implore you to not take it.